# How to use the module in a different class or form in same vb project?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I need to use already created module of database connection code in a different class in same vb project

I need the code block to recall a module in another class of the same project. I want to know how to connect the module with a new class in the same vb.net file.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. VB Modules are static and the variables and functions they contain are available throughout your project as long as they are not Private.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a module `SomeModule.vb` in your App_Code folder:

```vb
Public Module SomeClass
    Public Function DoSomething(OneThing As String, AnotherThing As Integer) As String
    End Function
End Module
```

You should be able to reference this code anywhere in your project:

```
Dim NewString As String = DoSomething("A thing", 5)
```

You can do the same for any `Sub` procedures.

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates that an App_Code folder exists.

Comment: This is true. But where else would it be? If it wasn't in that folder, then it is implicit in the answer that it ought to be. So if no App_Code folder exists then creating one and putting the module in it should also address the problem.

Comment: What type of project even has an App_Code folder? I'm not sure but was that a Web Forms thing? Was it maybe a holdover from ASP? I've been building Windows and MVC apps for years and have never had an App_Code folder in any of them and never had a problem that adding one would solve.